# fetch data from two different tables in single function postresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to write function to get data from two different tables
My code:

```
create function
return table(a integer,b integer,c integer,k integer,l integer,m integer);

if(x=1) then
     select a,b,c from mst_1
else
     select k,l,m from mst_2
end IF;
end;
```

the problem is that two tables posses different columns, I'm getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated a case similar to yours, and it's just a matter of using the correct sintax.

If you have two tables like `test` and `test_other` like in my case

```
create table test (id serial, name varchar, surname varchar);
insert into test values(1,'Carlo', 'Rossi');
insert into test values(2,'Giovanni', 'Galli');

create table test_other (id_other serial, name_other varchar, surname_other varchar);
insert into test_other values(1,'Beppe', 'Bianchi');
insert into test_other values(2,'Salmo', 'Verdi');
```

you now want a function that returns the 3 columns from `test` if an input parameter is 1, the 3 columns from `test_other` otherwise.

Your function will look like the following

```
create or replace function case_return(x integer) 
returns table(id integer,value_1 varchar, value_2 varchar)
language plpgsql 
as
$$
begin
  if(x=1) then
     return query select test.id,test.name,test.surname  from test;
  else
     return query select test_other.id_other, test_other.name_other, test_other.surname_other from test_other;
  end IF;
end;
$$
;
```

The function always returns the columns `id`, `value_1` and `value_2` as per definition even if your source columns are different

```
defaultdb=> select * from case_return(0);                                                                                                                                                                     id | value_1 | value_2 
----+---------+---------
  1 | Beppe   | Bianchi
  2 | Salmo   | Verdi
(2 rows)

defaultdb=> select * from case_return(1);                                                                                                                                                                     id | value_1  | value_2 
----+----------+---------
  1 | Carlo    | Rossi
  2 | Giovanni | Galli
(2 rows)
```